My question or answer was denied
Is my pseudorandom generator difficult to guess the next output?
My ask was hold on.
Why did my ask hold on?
I do not know what I do.
Should I ask someone else to translate? If so, who should I ask?
By the way, the program is also posted.

You can also put things in your native language as a comment.  Although, we generally post in English, many of us speak other languages as well.  Between the original post, and the notes, someone might be able to edit your post to make more sense.

@cryptomania   When I see a new post from you, I will be sure to edit it fast if that is needed.  There are a lot of people here who will use their time to help you out.

My problem is that I can not describe my concept as a correct mathematical proposition. What should I do to be able to do that?


My ask was hold on. Why did my ask hold on?

Part of the problem is the language barrier. Incomplete and/or malformed sentences can make it extremely difficult to determine what is being asked at all.
For example "My ask was hold on" is not a meaningful sentence in english. I have to guess that it is supposed to say "My question was put on hold".
Why it was closed
On that note: There is a marker on your question that says why it was closed. It says:

put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Ilmari Karonen, Maarten Bodewes♦ yesterday
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

Emphasis mine.

Should I ask someone else to translate?

If you know someone that knows both your language and english, and has better english skills, then asking them for help may be a good idea.

If so, who should I ask?

Friends/family/etc. We do not offer a translation service here.

By the way, the program is also posted.

It's not clear what this means or why it is relevant to your question here.
Recomendation
Take the time to ensure that your questions are legible and written in at least mostly correct english. Also, ensure that your questions are suitable for the site (e.g. cryptanalysis of complete algorithms is off-topic) and that each question is not in any way a duplicate of a previous one. It is difficult to see the difference between some of them, which may lead to them being closed as duplicates.
Note
Having enough questions closed and/or deleted can trigger a "question ban", where the system will prevent you from asking further questions until other meaningful and positive contributions to the site are made. I suggest that you take the time to ensure your questions are clear and on-topic to avoid this outcome.
